# Dropdown like button with a list of images to get selected

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I need to build a button in wpf to do the list below:

1. change it's color on mouseover
2. have a dropdown list of images so the user can pick one...

How I can get there?

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Use a ComboBox instead of a button when you want a dropdown list.

Comment: You can change template of a ComboBox to achieve this. Plenty of tutorials exist over the internet .. one of them ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a combobox instead.

Its even possible to give you combobox a button like style.
Just change the Style of the combobox.

[This blog post](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=40) can help you understand the styles.

Comment: ooh, i see,,,
my problem is that I need the button to have a little square on it's right side, and just with that thing the drop down should work, either way it should just do the change color thing...

thanks for your fast response by the way

Comment: Maybe then you should work with a dropdown withing a button. So you create a button, dont put anny click event behind it. and inside the button template you put the dropdownbox(combobox), where you change the style to a square without text. Like that you only ge the dropdown when clicked on the square. Rate if this is the answer :)

Comment: When you have a post, you see a number next to the post, With an arrow above(vote good) and under(vote bad) the number. You can even mark a answer as the right answer by clicking on the V. Then it will become green.    Besides that you can upvote a comment to. Just hover over the post, and next to it you see an arrow, click this to upvote an comment. greetings, and welcome to stackoverflow